# How to sort a List in a Specific Form?

Tags: c#, .net

I do have a list of string that contains

```
"aa1"
"aa2"
"aa3"
"bb1"
"bb2"
"bb3"
```

the values can be in any form where "aa3" can be at the the bottom or any other oder

I want to sort or reorder it in the form of

```
"aa1"
"bb1"
"aa2"
"bb2"
"aa3"
"bb3"
```

so how can I do that

Comment: Your question is unclear... What exactly is the logic you want them sorted by? Last Char and then the first char? Something else? Can there be any strings like `ab5` or `aaaa3`?

Comment: Also, you need to show us what you yourself have done to accomplish this so far.

Comment: I want to sort it by "aa" then "bb" "aa" always come first where "bb" always come second

Answer (score 3):

The following answer uses Linq to return a sequence of strings in the required order:

```
List<string> l = new List<string>
{
    "aa1",
    "aa2",
    "aa3",
    "bb1",
    "bb2",
    "bb3"
};

var result = l.OrderBy(s => s[2])
              .ThenBy(s => s.Substring(0, 2));

foreach (string str in result)
    Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Note that the original list stays unchanged.

---

Also you could extract these pieces of strings via an anonymous object:

```
var result = l.Select(s => new { Name = s.Substring(0, 2), 
                                 Num = s[2].ToString() })
                .OrderBy(o => o.Num)
                .ThenBy(o => o.Name);

foreach (var a in result)
    Console.WriteLine(a.Name + a.Num);
```

Comment: this solution does not work it works fine with the number at the end like 1, 2, 3 but does not work for something like "aa1", "aa1", "aa1", "bb1", "bb1", "bb1" I want it to work for something like that, as well as the increment in the "aa" and "bb"

Comment: @JeanDaniel what output do you want to get in this case?

Comment: @JeanDaniel the rules you described do not specify any order for these items except first - all `a`, then - all `b`

Comment: The specific order is to have aa1 and bb1 however if aa1 exist 4 time and bb1exist 4 time i still need to sort it like aa1bb1aa1bb1 before going to aa2 bb2 if aa2 and bb2 exist

Comment: @JeanDaniel and if, say, `aa1` exists 2 times, while `bb1` exists 10 times?

Answer (score 1):

You could just use LINQ:

```
var strings = new List<string> { "aa1", "aa2", "aa3", "bb1", "bb2", "bb3" };
var orderedStrings = strings
    .OrderBy(s => s[2])
    .ThenBy(s => s[1])
    .ThenBy(s => s[0])
    .ToList();
```

Comment: var strings =  new List<string> { "aa1", "aa1", "aa1", "bb1", "bb1", "bb1" };
            var orderedStrings = strings
                .OrderBy(s => s[2])
                .ThenBy(s => s[1])
                .ThenBy(s => s[0])
                .ToList();

Comment: this does not work for the form below  var strings =  new List<string> { "aa1", "aa1", "aa1", "bb1", "bb1", "bb1" };
            var orderedStrings = strings
                .OrderBy(s => s[2])
                .ThenBy(s => s[1])
                .ThenBy(s => s[0])
                .ToList();

Comment: @JeanDaniel What do you mean it doesn't work? It looks like it gives the right output to me...What output are you expecting? How is it differing from that output?